# Why is the output of a convolutional network so exponentially large?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to reproduce a unet result on Carvana dataset using [Ternausnet](https://github.com/ternaus/TernausNet) in PyTorch using Lightning.

I am using DiceLoss for that with sigmoid activation function. I think I am running into an issue of a vanishing gradient, because all gradients of weights are 0, and I see the output of the network with min value of order 10^8.

What could be the issue here? How can I address the vanishing gradient? Also, if I use a different criterion, I see a problem of loss going into negative values without stopping (for BCE with logits, for instance).

Here is the code for my Dice loss:

```
class DiceLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, logits, targets, eps=0, threshold=None):

        # comment out if your model contains a sigmoid or
        # equivalent activation layer
        proba = torch.sigmoid(logits)
        proba = proba.view(proba.shape[0], 1, -1)
        targets = targets.view(targets.shape[0], 1, -1)
        if threshold:
            proba = (proba > threshold).float()
        # flatten label and prediction tensors

        intersection = torch.sum(proba * targets, dim=1)
        summation = torch.sum(proba, dim=1) + torch.sum(targets, dim=1)
        dice = (2.0 * intersection + eps) / (summation + eps)
        # print(intersection, summation, dice)
        return (1 - dice).mean()
```

Comment: Make sure your data is OK, and try to lower the learning rate. Use the standard BCE loss for debugging first.

Comment: Do you apply BatchNormalization and activation after convolutional layers?